# Xcode 8.3.2 Playground Console not Showing Anything

Tags: swift, xcode8

I am a beginning Swift programmer and I am making an area calculator in Xcode to practice my use of functions. However, when I finished writing my code I noticed that the console in Xcode would not print out anything. Is there anything wrong with my code or is it just that the Xcode console is kind of not working and needs to be fixed in the next update?

Here is my code:

```
func areaCalculator(length: Int, width: Int) -> Int {
    let area = length * width
    return area
}

areaCalculator(length: 8, width: 8)
```

What I meant for the code to do is to return 64 to the console, since I entered 8 for length and also 8 for width. However, the console is not responding and is showing nothing.

Here is a screenshot:[area calculator function, console result, and entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Mc55.png)

Another screenshot using rmaddy's method (revised): [areaCalculator function, console result, and entry using rmaddy's method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaY8I.png)

Answer (score 0):

1) Add print statement to print in console

```
let area = areaCalculator(length: 8, width: 8)
print(area)
```

2) Repeat the constant to show in the right panel

```
let area = areaCalculator(length: 8, width: 8)
area
```